how is the navigation in shell route in go_router package?
I have configured my router and I'm using shell route in there for my tabsScreen but now I don't know how to navigate to cartScreen in case of I'm using shell route.
here is my router :
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/cart_screen.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/details_screen.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/favorite_screen.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/introduction_screen.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/tabs_screen.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/models/plant.dart';

final router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const IntroductionScreen(),
    ),
    ShellRoute(
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        return const TabsScreen();
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/home_screen',
          builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/favorite_screen',
          builder: (context, state) => const FavoriteScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/cart_screen',
          builder: (context, state) => const CartScreen(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          path: '/profile_screen',
          builder: (context, state) => const ProfileScreen(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/details_screen',
      builder: (context, state) {
        final plant = state.extra as Plant;
        return DetailsScreen(
          plant: plant,
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
);

and this is my tabsScreen :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/cart_screen.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/favorite_screen.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:herbal_store/screens/scan_screen.dart';
// import 'package:herbal_store/models/plant.dart';
// import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
// import 'dart:convert';
// import 'package:herbal_store/provider/favorite_plants_provider.dart';

class TabsScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const TabsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<TabsScreen> createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends ConsumerState<TabsScreen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget mainContent = const HomeScreen();
    
    if (_selectedIndex == 1) {
      mainContent = const FavoriteScreen();
    } else if (_selectedIndex == 2) {
      mainContent = const CartScreen();
    } else if (_selectedIndex == 3) {
      mainContent = const ProfileScreen();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: mainContent,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            isScrollControlled: true,
            context: context,
            builder: (ctx) {
              return const ScanScreen();
            },
          );
        },
        shape: const CircleBorder(),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/code-scan.png',
          width: 30,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 6,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                onItemTapped(0);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
              color: _selectedIndex == 0
                  ? Colors.green.shade800
                  : Colors.grey[600],
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                onItemTapped(1);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
              color: _selectedIndex == 1
                  ? Colors.green.shade800
                  : Colors.grey[600],
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                onItemTapped(2);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              color: _selectedIndex == 2
                  ? Colors.green.shade800
                  : Colors.grey[600],
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                onItemTapped(3);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
              color: _selectedIndex == 3
                  ? Colors.green.shade800
                  : Colors.grey[600],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I'm trying to navigate to cartScreen with context.go('/cart_screen'); but it's not working and instead of going to cartScreen , I'm going to tabsScreen. I don't know why!
if you need more information please tell me.
